# Finding matrix P given a matrix Q and eigen value of PQ is -3.

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Q = [v1 v2 v3], where v1 = (0,2,0), v2 = (-1, -3, 0), v3 = (0,0,-1).
Is there any shortcut for these type of questions?

Comment: Have you found the determinant of $Q$? Then you can use the fact that $\det (PQ)  = (\det P)(\det Q)$.

Comment: @TobyMak sorry, made a mistake, its actually the eigen value.